# ReactJS: render Parent in condition of childs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I render a parent Component in condition of its childs?
I would like to disable the Button in parent if any of the childs is invalid.
But the validation is inside of the child Component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: [
      {type: "text", value: ""},
      {type: "email", value: "not valid email"}
    ]};

  isAnyChildInvalid(){
    // How can I get information about my childs
  }

  render(){
    <div>
      this.state.data.map((item, index) => <Child key={index} data={item} />
      <button disabled={isAnyChildInvalid()} label="send">
    </div>
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  isValid(){
    let valid = true;
    switch(this.props.data.type){
      case "text":
        break;
      case "email":
        valid = (/\w+@\w+\.\w+/).test(this.props.data.value);
        break;
      default:
        valid = true;
    }
    tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot(valid);
    return valid;
  }

  tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot(valid){
    // How to tell Parent that i am valid or not?
    // The validation is used before any changes to input is done
  }

  render(){
    <input type={this.props.data.type} value={this.props.data.value} className={this.isValid() ? "valid" : "invalid" }/>
  }
```

I dont like to move all the validations to Parent Component because Childs are used in another Parent Component again.

Comment: How about you pass a callback to the child and notify the parent whenever the state of the child updates (valid/invalid)

Comment: The validation check is run initial before any changes of the child. And I cannot setState in callback in render.

Comment: Since a controlled input's state is usually part of the parent's state, the parent has full access to all input values and can therefore easily validate them. So if the validation isn't supposed to be part of the parent, just move it outside the parent: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-villani-gc6f7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Data in React flows only in one direction, so there is no way that you pass data from Child to Parent. But you can pass a function from Parent to Child that takes some arguments that you can then pass in the function call inside Child Component.

I would do something like this.
First in the Parent Component I would create a function that has a "invalid" argument which will be boolean.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: [
      {type: "text", value: ""},
      {type: "email", value: "not valid email"}
    ]};

  isAnyChildInvalid(invalid){
    if (invalid) {
      doSomething();
    }
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Then I would pass this function to the Child Component via props.

```html
  render(){
    <div>
      this.state.data.map((item, index) => <Child validateChild={this.isAnyChildInvalid} key={index} data={item} />
      <button disabled={isAnyChildInvalid()} label="send">
    </div>
  }
```

Then in the Child component I would call the function passed from Parent inside tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot function.

```js
  tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot(valid){
    this.props.validateChild(valid);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what can I do in doSomething() ? this.setState is not possible, because it is done in render and will cause error.

Comment: Right, instead of calling tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot inside isValid function. You could create a handler for onChange on that input element. You would need to call isValid inside that handler to get information about validity of the data and then call tellParentThatIAmValidOrNot. This way you could call setState without getting an error, since it will only be called, when input text changes.

Comment: But that is my problem, the validation check should be done before any changes of the user.

Comment: To do validation check before any user input, you can use componentDidMount() lifecycle method. It is called only once, when component was mounted. Inside this method you could called this handler too. So to sum up, you would have a handler that would be attached to onChange event on input and also it would be called once on componentDidMount() method.

Comment: The data can be also changed by an axios request. i know, that this was not inside my example, so sorry for this. So I only can use componentDidUpdate or shouldComponentUpdate and both of them are not really suitable for setState. Maybe I have to create a static method for child with all the calculation and use them in parent as well. But this has the benefit, that the code has to run twice. Once in render of child to get the className and once in render of parent to disable the button. Except you have another good idea.

Comment: It's not a problem actually, componentDidUpdate is fine for state change as long as you provide comparisions. So something like this if (prevProps.data.type !== this.props.data.type), then it is fine to call validation and state change inside that if statement and it will only be called when type variable is changed.